# Ways to define an ASP.NET MVC Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I was wondering if you could show me all the various ways to declare routes in ASP.NET MVC (1 and 2).  Please explain each method of defining a route, how it is used, and what case it covers.

Here is an example of what I am hoping to collect here:

```
routes.MapRoute("Directors",
    "Directors/{filter}/{skip}",
    new { controller = "Directors", action = "Index", skip = 0, filter = "" },
    new { skip = @"\d+", filter = @"^[a-zA-Z]+.+" });
```

`Directors` = the name of the route.  `Directors/{filter}/{skip}` = the url definition.  `new { controller = "Directors", action = "Index", skip = 0, filter = "" }` = the default for this route.  `new { skip = @"\d+", filter = @"^[a-zA-Z]+.+" }` = the constraints for this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first port of call would be the ASP.NET learning [pages](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Routing) on routing.

I think this may also be a good use of the Community Wiki feature, as the question you're asking a pretty vague question where there are not real answers, just good documentation on routes.