# Asp.net Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to define an ASP.NET MVC Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382473/ways-to-define-an-asp-net-mvc-route)

I'm trying to build a custom route that will take whatever comes under `Test/page?id=XXX`
and trigger my route handler.

My issue is how to get the id value

This is what i have in mind

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("Test", new Route("Test/page?id=XXX}", new RouteHandler()));
```

Comment: You mean you have a custom `RouteHandler` class?

Answer (score 1):

This version is for use in global.asax, but try:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Test",
    "Test/page?id={id}",
    new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" },
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

That last optional argument will limit the id's to numeric, for better certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Test is a Controller and Page is an Action

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route 
{
   Url = "[controller]/[action]/[id]"
   Defaults = new { action = "Index", id (string) null },
   RouteHandler = typeof(MvcRouteHandler)
});
```

but routing is very much context dependent. You need to look into your other routes and ensure that this route is placed in the right order.

Comment: will this work if i want to redirect from an incoming url like : www.some.com/test/page.aspx?id=44

Comment: where do you want the above URL to be routed? Which action method to be called?

Comment: I want to trigger a custom Handler that will do a basic server redirection RouteTable.Routes.Add("Test", new Route("Test/page.aspx?id=XXX}", new RouteHandler()));

Answer (score 0):

```
if (RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("customerId"))
  return RouteData.Values["customerId"].ToString();
```